# Wrong date when is echoed from mysql database

Tags: php, datetime

May be is really silly and newbie question but I have date saved in database like this: `2016-05-06 06:13:52`
Then I echoed date on the page like this

```
date('F j, Y', $row['start_datetime'])
```

but instead to get date like `May 06, 2016` i've got printed date -> `December 31, 1969`.. How is this happen? From where I got December 31, 1969?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
date('F j, Y', strtotime($row['start_datetime']));
```

Comment: Thanks but still same date.. December 31, 1969

Comment: try echo $row['start_datetime'] and check the date really coming from databse , there might be a problem

Comment: Nothing.. doesn't see anything when `echo $row['start_datetime']` .. I also doesn't see anything when `print_r($row['start_datetime'])` which is really strange

Comment: that is because you have empty field in database 'start_datetime'

Comment: Well this is what happen when man doesn't rest properly.. It was really silly  and stupid mistake by me. Field is `upload_date` not `start_datetime`. Thank's

Comment: And yes .. it is not only this I need also `strtotime` as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = new \DateTime($row['Date']);
$date->format('F j, Y');
```